# I'm using youtube v3 api to fetch my channel videos include public and private but here I got only public videos in response not private video

Tags: node.js, api, oauth-2.0, google-api, youtube-api

I'm using the bellow code for videos but in response I,m getting  only public videos not private

```
var axios = require('axios');
var data = '';

var config = {
  method: 'get',
   url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=AIzaSyAN0JBam9fXSldvwr10p4HInktzXmUXOnw&channelId=UCArmHom34p_A4xazZsZdqQg&order=date&part=snippe',
      headers: { 
           'Authorization': 'Bearer ya29.a0ARrdaM8lJdzzwA-gMtxC8Bwy-sfT0_CzKK8JqOT3i0CB55ThUOf5VRUQUf5vNzsx2VN3Rx9dyarESUB-OT-rYJbwb1Pfuy0rDaqto6-uQ9ftCgcKoZUq6axBvfVdzrf7ktP4BswothrkzkBzrHiGdl7VO_qh'
},data:data}       

   axios(config).then(function (response) {
       console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
   }).catch(function (error) {
       console.log(error);
   });
```

Comment: are you authenticated to the proper channel?

Comment: i have  authenticated the channel properly

Comment: Well if its only showing you the public ones then you have not authenticated as the owner of the channel or someone who has access.   Or you have not authenticated to the proper channel.  Remember YouTube api is channel based when you login and submit the consent screen you must pick a channel this is the channel you have access to.